# How to use IServiceProvider inside IServiceCollection.Configure()

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

Is it possible to use `IServiceProvider` inside `IServiceCollection.Configure()`?

I see no overload on `Configure()` to accept something like `Func<IServiceProvider, T`>. Other extension methods, like `IServiceCollection.AddScoped()` have an overload which accepts `Func<IServiceProvider, T>`.

I would like to do something like this:

```
public static void AddCommandHandlers(this IServiceCollection services, Assembly assembly)
{
    // CommandExecutor has a dependency on CommandHandlerFactory
    services.AddScoped<CommandExecutor>();

    services.Configure<CommandHandlerFactory>(myFactory =>
    {
        // How can I use IServiceProvider here? Example scenario:

        foreach(Type t in FindHandlers(assembly))
            myFactory.AddHandler(serviceProvider => serviceProvider.GetService(t));
    });
}
```

The goal is to be able to call `AddCommandHandlers` extension method **multiple times**, for different assemblies, and append found handlers (using DI) to the same `CommandHandlerFactory`, so that `CommandExecutor` can just call the factory to obtain a handler.

Or maybe there is another way?

Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can call the BuildServiceProvider() extension method on the IServiceCollection at any time to build a ServiceProvider.  You'll need 
 Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

It will obviously only include any services which have already been added to the collection so you'll need to call things in the correct order.

```
IServiceProvider sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could register each command handler against a common interface:

```
foreach(Type t in FindHandlers(assembly))
    services.AddScoped<ICommandHandler>(t);
```

Then you could make the factory accept `IEnumerable<ICommandHandler>` as a constructor parameter.

```
public class CommandHandlerFactory
{
    public CommandHandlerFactory(IEnumerable<ICommandHandler> handlers)
    {
        foreach(var handler in handlers)
           AddHandler(handler);
    }

    // The rest of the factory
}
```

Or, if you can't change the constructor, you could setup the factory like this:

```
services.AddSingleton(serviceProvider =>
{
    var factory = new CommandHandlerFactory();

    foreach(var handler in serviceProvider.GetServices<ICommandHandler>();
        factory.AddHandler(handler);

    return factory;

});
```